# sbjson does not print id correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi i'm returning a json string as follows:

```
{data,[{"id":1,"text":"blabla"},{"id":2,"text":"blabla2"}]}
```

When i try to print with NSLog like so:

```
NSLog(@"id: %@",[temp objectForKey:@"id"]);
```

i get large numbers, not the id.
If i enclose the the id's in quotes, things are fine.

Is there a way to decode the string when integers don't have quotes?

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to use integerValue method to convert object to integer.

```
NSLog(@"id: %d",[[temp objectForKey:@"id"]integerValue]);
```

thxs for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is a bit wonky. Also `-objectForKey:` takes an NSString for an argument, so be sure to prepend the quotes with `@` to signify an NSString constant.

```
NSLog(@"id: %@", [temp objectForKey:@"id"]);
```

Comment: oops..thx for catching my typo....so this formatting is not correct for sbjson?thx.

Comment: I was referring to your formatting in the NSLog. Note how the quotes close before the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your string format.  Instead of

```
NSLog(@"id: %@),[temp objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Try using this:

```
NSLog(@"id: %d),[temp objectForKey:@"id"];
```

%@ is only for strings, and in your case, when the ID is not quoted, it's an integer and you should use %d instead.

Comment: In my experience with SBJsonParser, all of the values are `NSString`s.